# Git push using SSH private key on Windows

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

After these commands,

```
git remote add origin server:<repo>.git
git push origin master
```

I need to enter a password. But I want to use my private ssh key to authenticate to the server only. I'm able for instance to connect to the server with that private key, but I don't know how to push a git repository using it.

My public key ofc is added to the authorized keys on the server.

Comment: Do you made your SSH key with password?

Answer (score -1):

Your server need to support ssh or [gitosis](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Gitosis) in order to do it.
Gitosis:

In your cae you mentioned that you do have ssh connection so you simply have to set the remote with the ssh protocol

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://......

# or
git remote set-url origin git@...
```

---

#### how to configure ssh key path for git

- Open a terminal window.
- Edit the `~/.ssh/config` file.
- If you don't have a config file, create one.
- Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

  ```
  Host <Host Name>
  HostName AAAAAAA.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<key for the given host>

  Host <Host1 Name>
  HostName BBBBB.org
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<host 2 key>
  ```

Comment: I don't think that the problem is from the server, i think it's from the client side. I feel like git don't know where is the private key to use. And after trying what you said i got this message : "Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

Comment: Update the answer and added code - how to map ssh keys for git

Comment: Hi, i feel like it's getting better. But i have a new problem message : (Load key "privateKey.ppk": invalid format).